# Cloud-init runcmd syntx of a command that adding a line to file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, user-data, cloud-init

I'm trying do this simple command but it keeps failing:

```
 echo "secret_backend_command: /home/ec2-user/dd-get-secrets.py" >> /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml"
```

I tried all the following:

```
        - [ sh, -c, echo "secret_backend_command: /home/ec2-user/dd-get-secrets.py" >> /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml ]

        - 'sh -c "echo \"secret_backend_command: /home/ec2-user/dd-get-secrets.py\" >> /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml"'

        - sh -c "echo 'secret_backend_command: /home/ec2-user/dd-get-secrets.py' >> /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml
```

any idea how to fix this quotes ?

> note I tested with another file rather than datadpg.yaml because I'm
>   getting Permission denied for this one.

examples I found in [here](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.7/topics/examples.html?highlight=string#run-commands-on-first-boot) didn't work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I changed the way of doing it and instead of having it in the yaml list in runcmds, I created a script and instead put this command inside and call the script in the runcmds. By doing so, I got rid of the tricky handling of ":" and quotes in cloud-init.

```
  UserData:
    'Fn::Base64': !Sub |
      #cloud-config
      write_files:
        - path: /home/ec2-user/update-datadog-config.sh
          permissions: 0744
          owner: root
          content: |
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            set -e
            echo "secret_backend_command: /home/ec2-user/dd-get-secrets.py" >> /etc/datadog-agent/datadog.yaml
      runcmd:
        - bash /home/ec2-user/update-datadog-config.sh
```